# Inject method in OpenTelemetry

Tags: java, open-telemetry, jaeger, opentracing, distributed-tracing

We are migrating from open-tracing to open telemetry .

We have inject function like below in open-tracing.

```
getTracer().inject(getActiveSpanContet(), Builtin.HTTP_HEADERS, new TextMapAdapter(contextValues));
```

Could some one please help what would be equivalent for same in openTelemetry? I tried searching on google I couldn’t get equivalent for same .

Answer (score 1):

OpenTelemetry has a similar `inject` method on the [Propagators API](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/manual/#context-propagation)

```
openTelemetry.getPropagators().getTextMapPropagator().inject(Context.current(), transportLayer, setter);
```

Comment: thanks Tyler for your reply , I have seen this  , here transport layer expectation is to create new http connection , but in open telemetry there is no need to create new http connection right ?

Comment: `transportLayer` would be the http request that is passed to the setter for updating the http headers according to the configured propagator. The link I provided shows the full example.